# Problems when using inherited(copied) class of sympy.core.Add and sympy.core.Mul

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following problem:

I have created my own copies of classes sympy.core.Add and sympy.core.Mul by defining

```
from sympy.core import Add, Mul

class jyrAdd(Add):    
        pass

class jyrMul(Mul):
        pass
```

The reason for this copying is that I want to add a color attribute to these classes to print different parts of an equation with different colors.

This almost works. But if I create an expression as follows problems occur:

```
ex1 = jyrAdd(2,3, evaluate = False)
ex1 = jyrMul(3,ex1, evaluate = False)
ex1 = jyrAdd(1,ex1, evaluate = False)
```

The two first steps are Ok but after the third step the expression ex1 gets broken and the debugger tells that `Unable to get repr for class 'jyrAdd'`

If I try to print the expression, the system crashes because the wrapper cannot find the correct way to show the expression.

If the first line of the code is replaced with line using the `sympy.core.Add` class

```
ex1 = Add(2,3, evaluate = False)
```

there is no problem. There are no problems either, if the first line would be

```
ex1 = jyrAdd(x,3,evaluate = False)
```

I don't know what to do with this problem and I would be thankful for any help. I am using python 2.7 and sympy 0.7.5.

Comment: Some problems relating to class inheritance have been solved in SymPy 1.0. Tbe error message in SymPy 1.0 is different. If you want to report a bug, I'd suggest to use the latest SymPy version.

Comment: I think it's a problem in the cache or related to some python magic (at least in the latest master branch).

Comment: It's probably an instance of https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6751